# How many numbers N satisfy N consecutive positive integers add to 2013?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, diophantine-equations

How would you find how many numbers N there exist such that N consecutive positive integers add to 2013? (Assume that N=1 is a valid case whose solution is just 2013 itself).

To clarify, this, when N=2 then 1006,1007 is a solution. If N=3 then 670,671,672 is a solution and so on. How many values of N exist such that this can happen?

---

I got that the equation for N consecutive integers to add up to 2013 is

$Nx\; +\; N\frac{\left( N-1 \right)}{2}\; =\; 2013$

where $x$ is the first term. However, I have no idea how to find the number of solutions to this diophantine equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$a+(a+1)+(a+2)+\cdots+(a+(N-1)) = Na + \dfrac{N(N-1)}2 = 2013$$
Hence, we need
\begin{align}
N(2a+N-1) & = 1 \times 4026\\
& = 2 \times 2013\\
& = 3 \times 1342\\
& = 6 \times 671\\
& = 11 \times 366\\
& = 22 \times 183\\
& = 33 \times 122\\
& = 61 \times 66\\
\end{align}
Now try out all these cases noting that $2a+N-1 > N$ for $a>1$.

You obtain the following pairs $(a,N)$ as solution:
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
& (a,N)\\
\hline
1 & (2013,1)\\
2 & (1006,2)\\
3 & (670,3)\\
4 & (333,6)\\
5 & (178,11)\\
6 & (81,22)\\
7 & (45,33)\\
8 & (3,61)\\
\hline
\end{array}

Comment: How do you try out the cases?

Comment: Do you just set N equal to the smaller of the two divisors and see if there exists an integer solution to a such that N(2a + N - 1) = the product of the 2 divisors?

Comment: @user2612743 Yes. Note that these are the only possibilities.

Comment: What would you do if instead of 2013 you were provided a larger number? The list of factors would get very large -- what alternate method (if there is one) could you use?

Comment: @user2612743 Even for a large number, the same method works in principle. If you have a large number of factors, then note that $N$ and $2a+N-1$ must be of opposite parity. So you can remove some of the cases, but still there could be potentially a large number of cases and almost all of them will give rise to a valid solution.